# Chromedriver Failed to grant sandbox access to cache directory c:\user\XXXX\Appdata\Local\Temp\4\scoped_dir11223\default\cache

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am using ChromeDriver to run chrome version 95.X.X. I am getting the error in the ChromeDriver command window
**Failed to grant sandbox access to cache directory c:\user\XXXX\Appdata\Local\Temp\4\scoped_dir11223\default\cache: The specified procedure could not be found.**

The ChromeDriver window doesn't close itself on Driver.Quit() and multiple ChromeDriver windows are left open.

Is that require any permission on a folder to resolve this? I didn't see this error in the earlier version of Chrome. This problem is happening on Server (Windows 2016). But on the local desktop running Windows 10, I don't get this error and ChromeDriver window also closes on Driver.Quit.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, have you found out anything?

Comment: Could you try again with Chrome 96.X.X? In my case the error disappeared by updating.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me to solve this issue was to make sure that the application that starts the chromedriver is running with local admin rights.